# Select IDs where boolean property is true using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select IDs from list where boolean IsActive= true using linq .
My Model class MyModel. I want to select IDs from list where IsActive is true.

```
        List<MyModel> ModelEntities = new List<MyModel>();
        MyModel Model = new MyModel();

        Model.IsActive=true;
        Model.ID = 1;
        ModelEntities.Add(Model);

        Model = new MyModel();
        Model.IsActive=true;
        Model.ID = 2;
        ModelEntities.Add(Model);

        
        Model = new MyModel();
        Model.IsActive=true;
        Model.ID = 3;         
        ModelEntities.Add(Model);

    
        Model = new MyModel();
        Model.IsActive=False;
        Model.ID = 4;         
        ModelEntities.Add(Model);

        
        Model = new MyModel();
        Model.IsActive=true;
        Model.ID = 5;         
        ModelEntities.Add(Model);

        
        Model = new MyModel();
        Model.IsActive=False;
        Model.ID = 6;         
        ModelEntities.Add(Model);

        
        Model = new MyModel();
        Model.IsActive=False;
        Model.ID = 7;         
        ModelEntities.Add(Model);

        
        Model = new MyModel();
        Model.IsActive=False;
        Model.ID = 8;         
        ModelEntities.Add(Model);
```

I want result like {1,2,3,5 }. How can get those IDs using Where condition in linq.

Edited
I just want list of IDs where IsActive = true .

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? This is not a place where you tell us what you want and we do it for you. If you want to use LINQ, learn to use LINQ and then use it. If what you try doesn't work, then you have a question to ask here, showing us what you have tried and telling us what happened when you tried it.

Comment: What have you tried and what problem are you getting?

Comment: `ModelEntities.Where(  e => e.IsActive ).OrderBy( e => e.ID ).ToList();`

Comment: I just want list of IDs where IsActive = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ids = ModelEntities
            .Where(model => model.IsActive)
            .Select(model => model.ID)
            .ToList();
```